# What restrictions will the LGPL put on my code?

Tags: open-source, licensing, lgpl

I want to use [CxxTest](http://cxxtest.tigris.org/) for unit-testing in an application. I do not want to be forced to release source code or object files. The LGPL (under which CxxTest is released) is confusing on this issue.

Am I ok? Do I need to do something special?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, you'll be alright with the LGPL, however,

If it is a derivative work, then the terms must allow "modification for the customer's own use and reverse engineering for debugging such modifications."

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're not distributing your tests it's not something you need to worry about.

Comment: Seriously, if he distributed his tests, along with unmodified CxxTest binaries, he'd have to also distribute his source code? Or the CxxTest source code? I can see it if his tests depended on a version of modified CxxTest, but _un_modified?

Comment: I still don't think he would have to, I'm just saying as long as he's not distributing his tests it's not even an issue that he needs to worry about. If he is distributing them, then it might be a gray area. I'm not extremely familiar with CxxTest so I can't be sure on that.

Answer (score 1):

If money is involved, you need to consult with an attorney.  LGPL is not straightforward.